# Как правильно составить бд чтоб получить массив следующего вида?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Нужно получить в код `php`, после запроса, массив такого вида:

```
[
    'animal' => 'cat',
    'body' => ['head' => 1, 'paw' => 4],
    'ability' => ['run' => 10, 'jump' => 2]
]
```

На `json` делает, довольно, легко, через `mysql` как взаимодействуют таблицы не могу разобраться, как правильно спроектировать таблицу, сколько таблиц надо вообще создать?

Comment: Три таблицы: основная animal и ссылающиеся на неё body и ability.

Comment: как сделать чтобы при запросе по id получать не один массив со всеми значениями, а многомерный массив как в описании

Comment: Получать вложенные (внутренние) массивы в подзапросах.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select JSON_OBJECTAGG(cat, prop) description
from (select id, animal prop, 'animal' cat
      from animal
union all
      select animal_id, JSON_OBJECTAGG(name, cnt) prop, 'body' cat
      from body
      group by animal_id
union all
      select animal_id, JSON_OBJECTAGG(name, val) prop, 'ability' cat
      from ability
      group by animal_id) total
group by id
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0e60ad86318f5495e8dd6786357f3799)